# How to improve performance when working with data with only VARCHAR values on SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, varchar

When working with databases that contain only VARCHAR values in specific tables, how could we improve performance when updating such tables?

My problem with updating such a table is that when new data is acquired, it must be decided whether to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` such rows, however what can be done with big tables with at least 1000+ rows?

If the table was small I'd find it easy to just do a SQL query to find if the new values already exist, and to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` depending on the result. But if you're acquiring say 100+ new rows of data, some of which may or may not be already on the database, and some which may be completely new, I'm concerned so many queries will take an unnecessary amount of time to complete.

Could deleting all the contents on the database that share a certain value, say the same date, as the new data potentially be better than querying each row individually?

Example:

```
        1   2   3  ...   20
01/01  A1  A2  A3  ...  A20
01/02  B1  B2  B3  ...  B20
 ...
01/31  Z1  Z2  Z3  ...  Z20
```

After updating:

```
        1   2   3  ...   20
01/01  A4  A5  A6  ...  A23
01/02  B1  B2  B3  ...  B20
 ...
01/31  Z1  Z5  Z6  ...  Z20
```

Example 2:

```
        1   2   3  ...   20
01/01  A1          ...  A20
01/02  B1  B2  B3  ...  B20
 ...
01/31  Z1      Z3  ...  Z20
```

Example 2 after updating:

```
        1   2   3  ...   20
01/01  A4  A5  A6  ...  A23
01/02  B1  B2  B3  ...  B20
 ...
01/31  Z1  Z5  Z6  ...  Z20
```

Comment: Use `INSERT OR REPLACE`.

Comment: Taking it a step further use transaction based operations so you don't open/close for every item you insert/replace

Comment: Another approach could be add a timestamp column, return just the last (for each row) , eliminate the need to update command at all and perform eventually a process to remove all but the last timestamp for each record.

Comment: I'm looking into `REPLACE`, is it supposed to work with previously non-existent values as well? See new example in question for further explanation.

Comment: I figured it out, turns out I had to make the fields I wanted to be unique `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing is worse than reading (because the database also has to read some pages before it can modify the table), so you should avoid doing DELETEs or REPLACEs that you do not actually need.

(The REPLACE statement always deletes the old row (if it exists) before inserting the new one, so it is as bad as DELETE.)

It does not matter whether the REPLACE statement or your own query searches for the old row, so you might as well do it yourself to be able to avoid the INSERT if it is not needed.

Lookups are extremely fast when the table is properly [indexed](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html), i.e., when there is an index on the column(s) whose values are used for searching.

Comment: This was my first idea however I'm not sure if it'd work out with a compiled statement I build to execute everything in a transaction. I find it already much faster than using individual `INSERT`s but I still need to choose whether to `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Comment: Your question does not mention compiled statements or transactions.

Comment: I am aware, it was suggested in a comment on the other answer. I'm sorry for the confussion.